# Silverlight : X:Type in Silverlight while converting WPF application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xtype

I am converting a functionality from WPF to Silverlight (New for me) and I am having trouble with the x:Type attribute. Here is my xaml

```
 <sdk:TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
        <sdk:TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="sdk:TabItem">
                <toolkit:DockPanel>
                    <Button Name="btnDelete" toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Null TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                    <Image Source="/delete.gif" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:TabItem}, Path=Header}"/>
                </toolkit:DockPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
```

The X:Type is not found.

```
<Button Name="btnDelete" toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Null TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
```

Is there a way I can support the x:Type markup in silverlight?

Comment: Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322(v=vs.110).aspx): `In fact, Silverlight does not currently support {x:Type} in its XAML language support, and does not accept {x:Type} usages outside of a few circumstances that are intended to support WPF-Silverlight XAML migration. Therefore, the typename-as-string behavior is built-in to all Silverlight native property evaluation where a Type is the value.` Therefore try this: `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=Name}"`

Comment: Unfortunately not. Type 'TabItem' was not found. Could there be any alternative workaround?

Comment: how about `AncestorType=sdk:TabItem`?

Comment: Working now. Excellent.